# Происхождение слова "небеса"

Tags: этимология

Читал две версии происхождения слова "небеса". Первая — от "нет бесов", а вторая — от латинского nebula - облако. Но что-то мне они обе кажутся какими-то не очень убедительными.
А что скажут знатоки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, Вы упростили версию Фасмера. Он выводит его из общей церковнославянской основы "небо", "нёбо" и т.д. и латинского nebula - туман:

Происходит от праслав. формы *nebo (род. п. -ese), от которой в числе прочего произошли: церк.-слав. небо, др.-русск. небо, ст.-слав. нєбо (род. п. нєбєсє; др.-греч.οὑρανός), русск. небо (народн. нёбо), укр. не́бо, белор. нёбо, болг. небе́, сербохорв. не̏бо (мн. небѐса), словенск. nеbó, чешск. nebe, словацк. nebo, польск. niebo (мн. niebiosa), в.-луж., н.-луж. njebjo. Балто-слав. основа на -еs восходит к праиндоевр.* nebh-, родственно лит. debesìs «облако», др.-лит. род. мн. debesų̃, латышск. debesis— то же, debess «небо» (d-, вероятно, под влиянием лит. dangùs «небо» или др. слова, ср.: греч. δνόφος, γνόφος «тьма»), др.-инд. nábhas ср. р. «туман, пар, небо», авест. nabah- ср. р. «воздушное пространство, небо», греч. νέφος ср. р. «облако», хеттск. nерiš (род. п. nерišаš) «небо», с расширением на -l-: греч. νεφέλη «облако», лат. nebula«туман; туча, облако», др.-исл. nifl- «темнота», njól «ночь», др.-в.-нем. nebul «туман».  М. Фасмер
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE

Так что латинское здесь наравне со славянским. От индоевропейской основы на -es у этого слова остался суфф.-ес,кот.отмечается как наращение во множ. ч.

Comment: Людмила, я не понял Вашей формулировки. Разве -es от индоевропейской ***основы***? Это вроде как праславянская ***флексия***. нет? Мы примерно об это с Надюшкой беседовали.

С остальным - согласен, если только спрашивающий действительно такой глубиной интересовался.

Comment: Я не про глубину, а про неприятие латинского nebula , если б всю версию прочитали, вопроса бы не возникло. Небо развилось из и.-е.*nebos,nebese вследствие утраты конечного -s , а значение первоначальное "туман, тучи, облака". Это не праславянская флексия, флексия(окончание)-О.Это суффикс, остаток в отдельных формах( во множ. ч.)от и.-е.

Answer (score 1):

По Фасмеру вторая версия.

Первая версия оооочень маловероятна. Поскольку есть и другие слова, сохраняюшие суффикс -ес- . Например, чудЕСа (телеса, словеса и пр.) Если не ошибаюсь, было в старославянском особое склонение для таких слов.

Comment: да, именно так.
С бесами - не катит. 
Даже опуская абсурдность самой постановки, бhс писался через ять, а небеса - через есть.
С чудесами и телесами - тоже все правильно. Мне только не нравится, когда говорят об особом склонеии таких слов в старославяснком языке. Во-первых не склонение, а скорее - наращение при некоторых падежных формах, а во=вторых это в русском что-то особенное. В ССЯ это была (и есть) вполне естественная продуктиная парадигма.

Comment: Я помню, что эти слова шли отдельной группой. О склонении с ходу точно не скажу, а подсмотреть негде, лекции далеко

Comment: Хабургаев? Гаманович? Елкина? Какое вино предпочитаете в это время суток? (С) 
Тут же проблема (если вообще есть проблема) не в том, как назвать эту "группу", склонением или еще как. Терминология - вещь привносная. Я обратил внимание только на слово "отдельная" и подобное. Я по сввоей серости не воспринимаю эту группу как что-то особое. Ключевое слово - "продуктиная (парадигма)".

Посмотрел. Гаманович называет всё это четвертым склонением, но относит туда вообще ***все*** слова, основа которых в косвенных падежах длиннее основы номинатива. Так что там полная каша.

Comment: Тысячу раз извиняюсь, если разговор показался бессодержательным.

Comment: Все хорошо, наоборот, интересно почитать.  У меня память девичья: тут помню, тут не помню.

Answer (score 1):

небо, развилось из не вода.  пар.  точно так же как невод. сетка для ловли рыбы, вынул -рыба, не вода. а буквочки  в-б дело рук монахов, иноземцев.латиняне приняли это слово,
а потом оно к нам вернулось. в северной италии сохранился гидроним--нева.то же и с невой--речкой, не от новой, а от того, что другой народ за рекой, не водь, НЕВО, так река называлась.
 а в греческом не библия, вивлия. вавилон. варвары.  не барбары. путаница. и с ней разбираться надо.

небо это не облако. оно голубое. для облака--есть слово влага, она там скапливается, и слова-как две капли воды. приставка о--влага. и небула-уже совсем не прет ни в какие ворота. прет в украинские--облаков нема, не было... над всей италией безоблачное небо, большую часть года.
 я на что намекаю, может, что нево---аналог голубой воды, как в ангаре, чистая была, как небо. Поэтому  и племя водь--голубоглазые ребята. В этом им отказать трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Слово небо происходит от от названия горы нево, на которой стоял Моисей. Гора находится на территории нынешней  Иордании. В арабском нет звука в , толко б. Кстати, там и таблица стоит - Nebo.

Comment: А источник столь необычного откровения не назовете? Вы рядом стояли? На каком языке Моисей с Б-гом разговаривали?

Comment: Гора такая есть, но к вопросу отношения не имеет.

Comment: а этимология горы разве не от этого же слова? наверно же отношение имеет

Answer (score 0):

БОГ, НЕБЕСА И DEBESIS (литовский язык)
Этимология (версия)

У древних ариев одним из эпитетов высшего божества  было слово « Bhaga» (сравните- «Бог») - «распределяющий», т. е. наделяющий своей судьбой каждое живое существо. Место обитания «Bhaga» - «Nabha», «nabhasa» ( ср. - «небо», «небеса»). В словах «nabha», «nabhasa» частица «bha» - это то, что осталось от слова «bhaga»; в русском языке в словах «небо», «небеса» от слова «Бог» уцелели только буква «б» и гласные («о», или «е»).

А теперь вспомним, как художники, отражая подсознательное людей, изображают  Бога: он сидит на облаке, как на троне, в окружении ангелов и архангелов, у которых за спинами крылья. Они же не боги, им для перемещения в пространстве нужны, подобно птицам, крылья! А Бог всемогущ, ему крылья не нужны! С другой стороны изображать Бога висящим в воздухе тоже как-то не этично! Вот и соорудил художник  опору в виде облака! А по-литовски слово «облако» обозначается словом « debesis». Сравните звучание слов «небеса» и «debesis» - в обоих словах тот же корень.

Т. е. на санскрите слова «nabha» и «nabhasa» означают неопределенное место обитания «bhaga»; на русском языке слова «небо», «небеса» означают более конкретное место, находящееся над землей (внутри Земли обитают злые силы); на литовском языке слово «debesis» определяет еще более конкретное местоположение -облако.

Comment: Здесь мало научно обоснованных фактов. Точнее - вообще нет. Ну как можно этимологию возводить от художников что-то там изображающих?

Answer (score 0):

У древних ариев одним из эпитетов высшего божества было слово «Bhaga» (сравните «Бог») - «распределяющий», то есть наделяющий своей судьбой каждое живое существо. Место обитания «Bhaga» - «Nabha», «nabhasa» (ср. «небо», «небеса»). В словах «nabha», «nabhasa» частица «bha» - это то, что осталось от слова «bhaga»; в русском языке в словах «небо», «небеса» от слова «Бог» уцелели только буква «б» и гласные («о» или «е»).
А теперь вспомним, как художники, отражая подсознательное людей, изображают Бога: он сидит на облаке, как на троне, в окружении ангелов и архангелов, у которых за спинами крылья. Они же не боги, им для перемещения в пространстве нужны, подобно птицам, крылья! А Бог всемогущ, ему крылья не нужны! С другой стороны изображать Бога висящим в воздухе тоже как-то  не этично! Вот и соорудил художник опору в виде облака! А по-литовски слово «облако» обозначается словом «debesis». Сравните звучание слов «небеса» и «debesis» - в обоих словах тот же корень.
То есть на санскрите слова «nabha» и «nabhasa» означают неопределенное место обитания "bhaga"; в русском слова небо и небеса означают более конкретное место - над землей (внутри земли обитают темные силы); на литовском языке слово «debesis» определяет еще более конкретное местоположение - облако.